# Table Query in Azure

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

My filter string during a Table Query looks like below...

```
string FilterString = string.Format("PartitionKey eq '{0}' 
and RowKey ge '{1}' and RowKey le '{2}'", 
partitionKey, startsWith, startsWith);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd894031.aspx says you can do prefix matching for names. Lets say there are 3 names...

- batman
- superman
- spiderman

I would like the query to return both superman and spiderman when I set the startsWith to 's'

The query above works when I say

```
RowKey ge 's' and Rowkey le 't'
```

However, I would like this to work when it says...

```
RowKey ge 's' and Rowkey le 's'
```

**le** is being treated as **lt** and IMHO it shouldn't have behaved the way it does. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get back `superman` and `spiderman` (not sure how DC & Marvel Comics would agree to that but that's another story :)), the query you want to issue is:

```
RowKey ge 's' and Rowkey lt 't'
```

Now let's consider this query:

```
RowKey ge 's' and Rowkey le 's'
```

Basically this query will only return data where `RowKey` eq `s`. To take an example, consider `superman`. Now `superman` is definitely greater than `s` so your first expression (`RowKey ge 's'`) is `true` but at the same time your second expression (`Rowkey le 's'`) is `false` so the entire expression's result will be `false`.

**UPDATE**

To test strings, you could simply write a console application like the following:

```
        string a = "s";
        string b = "superman";
        string c = "sz";
        Console.WriteLine(b.CompareTo(a));//Prints 1
        Console.WriteLine(b.CompareTo(c));//Prints -1
```

As you can see from above, `superman` is greater than `s` and is lesser than `sz`.

Comment: Thanks for helping out. My question is... why is Rowkey le 's' false? I can understand why Rowkey lt 's' is false. What is the difference between le & lt then??

Comment: `le` is `less than or equal to` and `lt` is `less than`. So `"superman" <= "s"` is certainly false. HTH.

Comment: Sorry, I don't agree. < is false for obvious reasons... but it is equal to s and that's why it should have worked. I can easily code around it, but the reason I asked the question is to understand if this is a bug, or I am missing something.

Comment: Agree with Gaurav, "superman" is greater than "s" during string comparison.

Comment: Is there a documentation that supports this behaviour?

Comment: You could simply do a simple console application like the following:             string a = "s";
            string b = "superman";
            string c = "sz";
            Console.WriteLine(b.CompareTo(a));//Prints 1
            Console.WriteLine(b.CompareTo(c));//Prints -1

Comment: Thanks for taking the time Gaurav. Much appreciated. I see your point and stand corrected. If you could edit the answer a bit, I can undo my negative vote.

Comment: :) Updated my answer with sample console app as mentioned in my other comment.